# do not know how to remove sqlalchemy 1.4 warning about cache_ok

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I am using `sqlalchemy` 1.4.17 with postgres and have a `pytest-asyncio` test which calls a function that creates a record that contains a uuid.

```
async def create_user(session: AsyncSession, input_user_data):
     new_user = model.User(**dict(input_user_data))
     session.add(new_user)
     await session.commit()
```

```
class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = "user"
    id = Column(GUID, primary_key=True,
                server_default=DefaultClause(text("gen_random_uuid()")))
```

and it runs ok, but creates a warning

```
  sys:1: SAWarning: TypeDecorator GUID() will not produce a cache key because the ``cache_ok`` flag is not set to True.  Set this flag to True if this type object's state is safe to use in a cache key, or False to disable this warning.
```

and don't understand how to silence it. any help is appreciated!

Comment: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/custom_types.html?highlight=cache_ok#sqlalchemy.types.TypeDecorator.cache_ok

Answer (score 3):

thanks @snakecharmerb. that pointed me to what I was doing wrong. in case this helps anyone else, I was importing GUID from fastapi_utils and instead imported right from sqlalchemy

```
# from fastapi_utils.guid_type import GUID, GUID_SERVER_DEFAULT_POSTGRESQL
from sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql import UUID
```

```
class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = "user"
    id = Column(UUID, primary_key=True,
                server_default=DefaultClause(text("gen_random_uuid()")))
```

rather than change the fastapi utils lib, using the SQL alchemy typedecorator was much easier.

Comment: What is the difference between [`sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql.UUID`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/dialects/postgresql.html#sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql.UUID) and [`sqlalchemy_utils.types.UUIDType`](https://sqlalchemy-utils.readthedocs.io/en/latest/data_types.html?highlight=uuidtype#module-sqlalchemy_utils.types.uuid)?

Comment: I've also [just asked in sqlalchemy_utils](https://github.com/kvesteri/sqlalchemy-utils/issues/577)

Answer (score 2):

If for whatever reason you use a custom `TypeDecorator`, for example:

```py
class MyUUIDType(TypeDecorator):

    impl = sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql.UUID
    
    ...
```

Then you'll need to add `cache_ok = True` as a class member

```py
class MyUUIDType(TypeDecorator):

    impl = sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql.UUID
    cache_ok = True    

    ...
```

Surely do this only if your column's TypeDecorator is cacheable.